# How do you Reuse a DirectShow filter graph with different file

Tags: c#, directshow

I have an application the creates directshow graphs using filterGraph.RenderEx();
since 1it can take a long time to get the graph up and running, I would like to create a few graphs at the start of the app and then reuse them by changing the source file.  ie

1. play file1.wmv
2. wait for file to finish
3. change the graph to point to file2.wmv
4. play file2

How do you change the source file so you do not have to recreate the entire graph for the next file?

Edit:::

I am not trying to play files back to back, but overlapping.  The graphs are actually rendering to texture2d objects as part of a d3d application.

Here is what I am doing.
I am adding a sourceFilter using:

```
IBaseFilter sourceFilter;
int hr = filterGraph.AddSourceFilter(file, file, out sourceFilter);
/* We will want to enum all the pins on the source filter */

IEnumPins pinEnum;
hr = sourceFilter.EnumPins(out pinEnum);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

IntPtr fetched = IntPtr.Zero;
IPin[] pins = { null };

/* Counter for how many pins successfully rendered */
int pinsRendered = 0;

/* Loop over each pin of the source filter */
while (pinEnum.Next(pins.Length, pins, fetched) == 0)
{
     if (filterGraph.RenderEx(pins[0], AMRenderExFlags.None, IntPtr.Zero) >= 0)
         pinsRendered++;

     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pins[0]);
}
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pinEnum);
```

When the file is done playing, at some point in the future,I would like to set the source filter to another file(of the same type), so i don't have to completely rebuild the graph which can be very slow to create.
Is there something i can cast the sourceFilter object to that allows me to set it to another file?

Answer (score 1):

The GMFBridge can be used for this. There are ports to .NET AFAIK. Have a look at the GMFPlay application mentioned at http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html.

Using [intelligent connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can slow down the graph building process. Using direct connections should speed up the process as well.

Comment: Thanks for the Ideas!,  I saw the GMFBridge,It's really cool, but I don't think it is going to solve my problem...  I added some more details to my question above, If you have any other Ideas I am all Ears!!!

Comment: I wonder if you could call the IFileSourceFilter::Load method on the source filter, I guess that depends on the source implementation and also, would only work as long as you can assure that the media types don't change at all. Perhaps rather consider building the graph manually and seeing if that meets your timing requirements.

Comment: I will try the IfileSource filter load method. In order to use the Direct connect method I would need to already know all the filters needed. Would you recommend using graph edit to work out the filters needed?  Are the any websites that recommend a set of filters for a given type of media??

Comment: Ok, I have no idea if that works once the graph has been built. I usually use graphedit or graphstudio to figure out the graph. You just need to keep in mind that the available filters might differ from machine to machine, also depending on the OS.